# Find $\lim_{x,y\to0,0} \frac{x^3y^2}{x^4+y^8}$.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I am having trouble with the limit 
$$\lim_{x,y\to0,0}
\frac{x^3y^2}{x^4+y^8}$$
The thing is that I checked Wolfram and it says $0$
but I can't prove that

Thank you.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

No, this cannot be $0$. Consider approaching the origin $(0,0)$ along the path $(x,\sqrt x)$ with $x>0$ (i.e. make $y = \sqrt x$). Along this path, your limit becomes

$$\lim _{x \to 0} \frac {x^3 x} {x^4 + x^4} = \frac 1 2 .$$

Choosing a different path, for instance the path $(x, x)$ (i.e. $y = x$), the limit along this path becomes

$$\lim _{x \to 0} \frac {x^3 x^2} {x^4 + x^8} = \lim _{x \to 0} \frac x {1 + x^4} = 0 .$$

The fact that you obtain different limits along different paths shows that, in fact, the limit does not exist (and Mathematica is wrong once more, haha!).